# Why does Application_Deactivated not get called on a pivot page?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

For my Windows Phone 7 app, I have a main panorama page which opens up into a pivot control. The main panorama page correctly calls Activated/Deactivated, and restores correctly.

But after visiting the pivot page, pressing the Windows key doesn't call Deactivated.

When the app is relaunched with the back button, it goes right to how the page looked before tombstoning, but Activated is not called, and the page is not usable, and the back key doesn't work.

Has anyone else experienced this problem before?

Comment: Sounds like your app just isn't getting tombstoned... Why isn't it usable when the user resumes to it? Does it Tombstone correctly with the "Search" button (i.e. "Exit" button)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just go to the Start screen then your application ***MAY*** not get tombstoned. This is expected behaviour.

If you open another application or open search from within your application you should experience tombstoning.